# Hiding buttons/images shortcut?

Tags: iphone, image, button, hidden

Is there a shortcut for this code?

```
-(IBAction)reset{
    button1.hidden=NO;
    button2.hidden=NO;
    button3.hidden=NO;
    button4.hidden=NO;
    button5.hidden=NO;
    button6.hidden=NO;
    button7.hidden=NO;
    button8.hidden=NO;
    button9.hidden=NO;
    button10.hidden=NO;
    button11.hidden=NO;
    button12.hidden=NO;
    button13.hidden=NO;
    button14.hidden=NO;
    button15.hidden=NO;
    button16.hidden=NO;
    button17.hidden=NO;
    button18.hidden=NO;
    button19.hidden=NO;
    button20.hidden=NO;
    button21.hidden=NO;
    button22.hidden=NO;
    button23.hidden=NO;
    button24.hidden=NO;
    button25.hidden=NO;
    button26.hidden=NO;
    button27.hidden=NO;
    button28.hidden=NO;
    button29.hidden=NO;
    button30.hidden=NO;
    button31.hidden=NO;
    button32.hidden=NO;
    button33.hidden=NO;
    button34.hidden=NO;
    button35.hidden=NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There definitely must be ways for that :) It really depends on how you create and store your buttons. You can store them in array and process them in a loop:

```
for (UIButton* button in buttonsArray)
   button.hidden = NO;
```

You can also assign a unique `tag` property to a UIButton when you create them (this property is defined in `UIView` and available in all its subclasses). This way you do not need separate storage for buttons and you can also hide them in a loop:

```
for (int tag = min_tag_value; tag < max_tag_value;++tag)
    // Assume that self.view is a view that contains your buttons
    [self.view viewWithTag:tag].hidden = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Key Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/BasicPrinciples.html)

I think it would be something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <=35; i++)
{
    [self setValue:NO forKey:@"[NSString stringWithFormat:@"button%d", i]];
}
```